How to use a django-cms PlaceholderRelationField()
I have included a simple app to a django-cms 4.1.1 installation and connected it with an apphook following the tutorials.
models.py:
class Meeting(models.Model):
    # some fields above...

    body = models.TextField(_('body'),
        default='',
        blank=True
    )

    placeholders = PlaceholderRelationField()

    @cached_property
    def placeholder_test(self):
        return get_placeholder_from_slot(self.placeholders, "body")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('meetings:detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.start_date:%d.%m.%Y} - {self.location}: {self.title}'

I want to change the body field to become a Placeholder-Field. In django-cms < 4 this was done with body = PlaceholderField('body') but if I understand right this is obsolete in Version 4.
admin.py
from cms.admin.placeholderadmin import FrontendEditableAdminMixin
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Meeting


class MeetingAdmin(FrontendEditableAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Meeting, MeetingAdmin)

meeting_detail.html
{% block content %}
    {% render_placeholder meeting.placeholder_test %}
{% endblock content %}

But no placeholder appears in the frontend to be filled with plugins. How is this possible?

You also need to register the model to be frontend-editable in your cms_config.py. See here: https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/01-placeholders.html#registering-the-model-for-frontend-editing

The behavior changed in django-cms 4. Instead of declaring a field like my_field = PlaceholderField() do this:
models.py
# imports +
from cms.models.fields import PlaceholderRelationField
from cms.utils.placeholder import get_placeholder_from_slot
from django.utils.functional import cached_property

class YourModel(models.Model):
    # Your fields +

    placeholders = PlaceholderRelationField()
    
    @cached_property
    def placeholder(self):
        return get_placeholder_from_slot(self.placeholders, "The Placeholder")
    
    def get_template(self):
        return "your_app/yourmodel_structure.html"
    
    # Methods ...

yourmodel_structure.html
{% load cms_tags %}
{% placeholder "The Placeholder" %}

To render the Placeholder in the templates of your_app,for example
yourmodel_detail.html
{% load cms_tags %}
{% render_placeholder yourmodel.placeholder %}

views.py
# Imports + 
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

from .models import YourModel


# Views... +

def render_your_model(request, obj):
    return render(
        request,
        "your_app/yourmodel_detail.html",
        {
            "obj": obj,
        },
    )

def meeting_detail(request, id):
    # Get the object, here by id
    obj = get_object_or_404(Meeting, id=id)
    # Announce the object to the toolbar
    request.toolbar.set_object(obj)
    # Same as preview rendering
    return render_your_model(request, obj)

urls.py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'your_app'

urlpatterns = [
    # Paths +
    path('<id:id>/', views.yourmodel_detail, name='detail'),
]

admin.py
# Imports +
from cms.admin.placeholderadmin import FrontendEditableAdminMixin

from .models import YourModel

# FrontendEditableAdminMixin First!
class YourModelAdmin(FrontendEditableAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(YourModel, YourModelAdmin)

cms_config.py
from cms.app_base import CMSAppConfig
from . import models, views

class YourModelConfig(CMSAppConfig):
    cms_enabled = True
    cms_toolbar_enabled_models = [(models.YourModel, views.render_your_model)]

